# Wagtail: custom URLs for blog page categories?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

My blog pages have a type and a subtype.

I want blog page URLs to look like `mysite.com/pages/<blog_type>/<blog_subtype>/<blog_title>`

By default, they are just `mysite.com/pages/<blog_title>`

I can't think of a way to do this (I'm new to Wagtail). Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Routable pages will do what you're looking for:
https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/routablepage.html

It does complicate a few things though:

If you're worried about SEO, you should choose one path and add this as your [canonical link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) in your `<head>` section otherwise search engines won't know which to index (and also throw an error in the case of Google).

The basic would be `<link rel="canonical" href="{{ self.full_url} }">` but you'd need to change that to reflect your modified route.

You'd be better adding a property to those pages that generates the url for you.

You'd also need to override the default method for sitemap generation to add your custom url for these pages.

If you're indexing, you'll need to return the custom url in your search view as well.